# perf_event reports unexpected cache miss amount: accessing N elements in an array incurs 2N cache misses

Tags: c, linux, caching, perf

I'm trying to investigate the relationship between accessing array elements and cache misses. I wrote the following codes.

```
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <inttypes.h>

static long perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags) {
    int ret;
    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                  group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    long long count;
    int fd;
    char *chars, c;

    uint64_t n = 100000000;
    int step = 64;
    if (argc > 1) {
        step = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    chars = malloc(n * sizeof(char));

    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D |
                PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8 |
                PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16;
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
    pe.exclude_hv = 1;

    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        chars[i] = 1;
    }


    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

    // Read from memory
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += step) {
        c = chars[i];
    }

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
    read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

    printf("%lld\n", count);

    close(fd);
    free(chars);
}
```

It is easy to know that only n/step elements in the array chars are accessed and assigned to c. I think the number of cache misses should be n/step if step is larger than the cache line (64 usually). There is no problem when step is small, i.e.,the printed number of count is about n/step. However, if step is a large number, e.g., 1000000, count is equal to about 2n/step. This  has confused me for a long time. Could anyone explain this odd result?

Comment: Did you compile without optimization?  You'd assume the loads (and store) the compiler is doing on `i`, `n`, and `step` would all hit in cache, but `volatile char *chars` would be better.  Does your result scale with `n`, or is it possible some of the extra misses are just from library function calls?  Or with a small enough stride (step), L2 prefetch is locking on to this pattern, and can keep up with your un-optimized code?  Touching one cache line every maybe 6 cycles at best, given the loop-carried dep chain on `i`.

Comment: My other guess is TLB misses causing page-walks, if that event counts L1d accesses by the page-walker.  Perhaps an event like `mem_load_retired.l1_miss` would avoid that problem.  (That event exists on Skylake; you didn't say what CPU you're using.)

Comment: Hi, the code is compiled without optimization. The cpu I used is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz.@PeterCordes chars was declared to be volatile char *, the result did not change.

Comment: The point of using `volatile` is to let you enable optimization without optimizing away the loads you want to measure.  Of course the result doesn't change if you still don't enable optimization; in un-optimized code, everything is treated somewhat like volatile.